# can't get parameter value out of a trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the following code in my backbone view:

```
this.trigger('item-id-changed', itemId);
```

and here's the subscriber:

```
that.shopItemDetailedView = new ShopItemDetailedView({ model: shop });
                    that.shopItemDetailedView.on('item-id-changed', that.onModelChange);
```

in a different view. The question is how do I access the itemId that i passed during the trigger on the function onModalChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger):

> **trigger** `object.trigger(event, [*args])`
>
> [...] Subsequent arguments to **trigger** will be passed along to the event callbacks.

So if you say:

```
this.trigger('item-id-changed', itemId);
```

then the function listening for `'item-id-changed'` will get `itemId` as its argument:

```
onModelChange: function(itemId) {
    //...
}
```